# How do I convert the following LESS to SCSS

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm trying to convert a [www.bootswatch.com][1] theme from less to scss for my rails app.

Problem is I'm no expert on either SCSS or LESS :(

I've read up on some of the differences and I've figured variable differnces using @ and $

I've got an issue with the my LESS code , can someone tell me what the snipet below should be when converted  SCSS

```
// Buttons ====================================================================

.btn:active {
        .box-shadow(none);
}

.btn-group.open .dropdown-toggle {
        .box-shadow(none);
}

// Typography =================================================================

.text-primary,
.text-primary:hover {
        color: $brand-primary;
}

.text-success,
.text-success:hover {
        color: $brand-success;
}

.text-danger,
.text-danger:hover {
        color: $brand-danger;
}

.text-warning,
.text-warning:hover {
        color: $brand-warning;
}
```

When I run my app I'm getting the following message

> Invalid CSS after "   .box-shadow": expected "{", was "(none);"

Comment: find the mixin with the name `box-shadow`, you need that to process it.

Comment: Is `box-shadow` supposed to be a mixin?

Comment: And mixins are used like this in `SASS` - `@include box-shadow(pass in your values);` - you might want to take a look at using Compass - http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_shadow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the bootstrap SASS for ruby: [Bootstrap SASS Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass)

But to better answer your question try `@extend .box-shadow(none)`